# Bring Excel file to front when running Outlook VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a macro in Outlook to set the value of a cell in Excel file which is opening.

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim objExcel As Object, WB As Object, WS As Object
    Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    objExcel.Visible = True
    Set WB = objExcel.Workbooks("Book1.xlsm")
    WB.Activate
    Set WS = WB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    AppActivate "Microsoft Outlook"
    WS.Range("A1").Value = "hoho"
End Sub
```

It sets the value of the cell, but I still stand in Outlook.

How can I display the Excel file instead of Outlook?

Comment: You can just reactivate Outlook

Comment: I copied your line to my script, please look my script which edited above, but It get error "Invalid procedure call or argument". Please tell me what problem with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do that is to minimize the Application Window and then maximize it.

```
objExcel.WindowState = xlMinimized 
objExcel.WindowState = xlMaximized
```

Comment: I copied your line to my script, please look my script which edited above, but It get error "Invalid procedure call or argument". Please tell me what problem with it

Comment: Hello Thomas Sorry for late reply, I quite busy at school all day. Thank you for your answer, I checked your function but it still not display excel file. My excel is opening, I am standing in outlook, I would like when I run macro in outlook, it set cell in excel and show this file instead I use mouse click to this excel file on taskbar

Comment: Wonderful!!!, This is exactly what I expected. It's run very good and more than I imaged. I am very very thank you so much :D

Comment: Your welcome :).  Sorry that I misread your question on my phone.

Comment: Don't say sorry, I had to sorry because my question unclearly  However, You edited your answer very exactly and I am so glad about that, once again, Thank you so much :)